# Converting an array of single digits to an integer

Tags: java

For example:

I have an array {1,5,3,6,3}

I want to find a way to convert that to the int type.

So `int x = 15363` instead of `int[] d = {1,5,3,6,3}`

Suggestions?

Comment: No easy way to do this. You will need an algorithm to make this happen. For example: `String s = ""; for(int c: d) { s += c; } int x = Integer.parseInt(s);`

Comment: convert x to string and split string and convert splited string to int

Comment: @KickButtowski wrong variable for conversion.

Comment: OP wants an array to a single integer.

Comment: @shinjw Could you please convert your first comment to an answer, so that I can upvote it?  This is the "easy way to do this" that you deny the existence of, and is better than some of the answers here.

Comment: Do you need to handle the case if elements of the array are negative besides index 0?  If so all the string based conversions listed thus far will have issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cryin' out loud -- it's a simple conversion.  No fancy functions required.

```
int[] digits = {1, 5, 3, 6, 3};
int totalNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    totalNumber = (totalNumber * 10) + digits[i];
}
System.out.println(totalNumber);
```

Comment: +1 for showing me the obvious solution, I couldn't think of! still wouldn't see `Math.pow()` as fancy :)

Comment: Again be careful of overflow if that is important to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here a math-based approach:

A number like 15363 can be seen like this:

```
1*10^4 + 5*10^3 + 3*10^2 + 6*10^1 + 3*^10^0
```

the algorithm here uses the `Math.pow` method to calculate the `10^x` (*ten to the power of x*)

```
int[] digits = {1, 5, 3, 6, 3};
int totalNumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {                  
    totalNumber += digits[i] * Math.pow(10, digits.length-(i+1));
}
System.out.println(totalNumber);
```

Comment: This approach should be more efficient than a string based approach but  watch out for overflow (assuming overflow is undesired).

Comment: good point (had a bad feeling when using `int` for `totalNumber` but ignored it :) I guess this is an overall concern for every approach when turning an array of int into one single number

Comment: Yes overflow will always be a concern but other solutions may be handling it correctly.  For example solutions that use `Integer.parseInt` will throw an exception for overflow.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Iterate over the array of int.

2.) Append each digit using StringBuilder.

3.) Finally parse the number, to get the required result.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nums[] = { 1, 5, 3, 6, 3 };

        StringBuilder strNum = new StringBuilder(nums.length);

        for (int num : nums) {
            strNum.append(num);
        }
        int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(strNum.toString());
        System.out.println(finalInt);
    }
```

**Output**

```
15363
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could explain *how* to approach this type of problem, and also detail why you chose to implement the way you did. Otherwise, nobody learns anything.

Comment: If you are going to use this approach you may want to consider using the [StringBuilder initial size constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(int)). You may be able to get a "good" size estimate for "most of the time" based upon the size of your input array.

Comment: @JasonC as per your comment, explanation added.

Comment: @ScottMitchell as per your comment changes made, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @ScottMitchell - There's no real point in doing what you suggest.  The default of 16 is big enough for anything that's not going to overflow the `int` data type.  All your suggestion will do is to slow things down a tiny bit while we count the elements.  Better just to write `new StringBuilder()`.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Why take a default (assumed to be 16) when you could use 11 ( -(2^31)=-2147483648)?  I would say there is value in being explicit when it makes sense and clarifies expectations/limitations.

Comment: @DavidWallace "count the elements" - I'm not sure what this means but I'm not suggesting counting anything.  If by count elements do you mean `nums.length`?

Comment: @ScottMitchell It's a maintainability thing.  As soon as you put a constant into code, you're saying to anyone who works on the code in the future "this constant matters".  So if you write `new StringBuilder(11)`, you've written code with a particular intent - make a `StringBuilder` that starts out with a buffer of 11 characters.  But the fact is, the initial size of the buffer doesn't matter to anyone at all.  It's completely irrelevant, provided it's not enormous.  So it's better not to state it, so that future maintainers of the code know that it's unimportant.  So even though from the ...

Comment: ... computer's point of view, `new StringBuilder(16)` is identical to `new StringBuilder()`, from a human's point of view, these carry a slightly different nuance.  One of the arts of software development is making your code speak to humans, as well as speaking to the computer.

Comment: @DavidWallace The meaning behind 11 in this algorithm is that 11 is the maximum number of characters to represent an integer. In general if you don't know the initial size or don't have a good estimate than taking the default may be OK. However if you do have a good estimate or in this case know the maximum size (that is relatively small) I would argue you should use it for clarity and allocating memory responsibly. This is a general statement which applies to any containers which take an initial size for construction.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an algorithm to make this happen. For example:

```
String s = ""; 
for(int c: d) { s += c; } 
int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Comment: If you are going with the string conversion approach then use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

One (very inefficient) way to do this is to build a `String` out of your integer array, and then use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert it into an `int`.

In reality, you really never want to be doing this sort of conversion, especially not on a large scale.