# How to convert an array of integers to a single digit

Tags: javascript, arrays

let's say I have got an array of `[2, 4, 5, 6]`.

I want to be able to convert it to `2456`.

Is there an easy and elegant way to do this in JavaScript?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835717/converting-an-array-of-single-digits-to-an-integer) question.

Comment: Yes. [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: ... or, if you need the output to still be a number, `parseInt([2, 4, 5, 6].join(''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 5, 6];

const str = arr.join('');

console.log('string', str);
console.log('number', +str);
```

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about this :(